# Django + AJAX комментарии

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

Пытаюсь реализовать систему комментариев без перезагрузки страницы, но не выходит. Комментарии вставляются лишь после перезагрузки страницы, но AJAX не работает.

```
        <!-- COMMENT -->
    <div class="comment-section">
        <form action="{% url 'love:comment_urls' %}" method="POST" class='comment-form'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value={{i.pk}}>
            {{ comment_form }}
            <button type="submit" name="submit_c_form">
                Опубликовать
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div class="comment_set">
        {% if i.quotes_comment.all %}
        {% for com in i.quotes_comment.all %}
        <b>{{ com.user }}:</b>
        {{ com.body }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS код

```
 // COMMENT 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.comment-form').submit(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).serialize());
        var url = $(this).attr('action')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('Заработало')
                $('.comment-section').html(response['form']);
            },
            error: function (rs, error) {
                console.log(rs, error)

            }
        })

    })
})
```

Как я и сказал, вставляются комментарии только после перезагрузки, но когда опубликовать жму ничего не происходит.
Если изменить dataType на 'json', то вылазит ошибка parsererror.
Можете объяснить, что не так делаю?

Comment: Дак а что response возвращает при success. И зачем вы меняется форму, если нужно добавить комментарий? $('.comment-section').html(response['form']);

Comment: @Даня, честно говоря, я плохо знаю js, поэтому делаю по видео на ютубе. Это реализация одного из таких видео. Просто нужно, чтобы комментарий добавлялся без перезагрузки, но этого не происходит

Comment: там где console.log('Заработало'), исправьте на console.log('Заработало', response). В зависимости от того, что возвращается делаем на js, например, если возвращается весь список комментариев то, вместо $('.comment-section').html(response['form']); пишем $('.comment_set').html(response);